# How to combine many Spring test annotations in a single annotation?

Tags: java, junit, annotations, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot's convenient annotations on my test classes, for integration tests.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
@IntegrationTest
@Sql({"classpath:rollback.sql", "classpath:create-tables.sql"})
@Transactional
```

I found it quite ugly to copy/paste this whole block on each test class, so I have created my own `@MyIntegrationTest` annotation

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
@IntegrationTest
@Sql({"classpath:database-scripts/rollback.sql", "classpath:database-scripts/create-tables.sql", "classpath:database-scripts/insert-test-data.sql"})
@Transactional
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface MyIntegrationTest {
}
```

However, if I add the `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` in my new annotation, then JUnit will run with its default runner - which is not desirable.
So for now I have to use two annotations.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@MyIntegrationTest
```

I guess it is fine for now, but is there a way to combine these annotations, so I would be able to use a single annotation?

Comment: I guess this is the best what you can get... http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-meta

Comment: Ok I've dug a bit into JUnit code. The `AnnotatedBuilder` class is the one trying to detect any Runner via annotation, and they use: `RunWith annotation = currentTestClass.getAnnotation(RunWith.class);`, so it won't fetch any "annotation on annotation". Not sure why it was not implemented though, will ask the guys on their GitHub.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meta-annotations are not the only way of code reuse. We use inheritance instead:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
@IntegrationTest
@Sql({"classpath:rollback.sql", "classpath:create-tables.sql"})
@Transactional
public abstract class IntegrationTest {
}

public class FooTest extends IntegrationTest {

}

public class BarTest extends IntegrationTest {

}
```

Unlike meta-annotations, annotation inheritance from base classes is understood by both Spring and JUnit.

Comment: That's a right answer for me, even if I hoped having something else than inheritance. When the codebase grows inheritance always brings some coupling issues and it's quite hard to get rid of the abstract class later, but I guess that's the best thing I can get now.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work for me. when adding my `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation to the abstract class only, the application context did not load anymore.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, here's a blog post arguing against using inheritance in tests: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/unit-testing/3-reasons-why-we-should-not-use-inheritance-in-our-tests/ The main arguments are:

1. Inheritance Is Not the Right Tool for Reusing Code
2. Inheritance Can Have a Negative Effect to the Performance of Our Test Suite
3. Using Inheritance Makes Tests Harder to Read

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I've found some old discussions about this on the JUnit GitHub:

- https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/194
- https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/202

It is some sort of trade-off between readability and DRY-ness.

Allowing some meta-annotations could also slow down tools like IDEs.

I doesn't seem that it's on the way to be implemented any time soon, so for now I will have to keep my two annotations.